# How to consume Maven Components from Private Gitlab Repositories?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gitlab

## Problem

- We are trying to consume a Maven components in a private Maven repository... The dependency right now is not being pulled for some reason... I have declared the dependency in gradle as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'super_.platform.client', name: 'client-feign', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
   maven {
     url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22268428/packages/maven"
   }
}
```

- When running `gradle eclipse` to pull the dependency, the command fails with the following:

```
[INFO] Resolving super_.platform.client:client-feign:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT with transitive dependencies
[WARNING] Missing POM for super_.platform.client:client-feign:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-06T19:49:27Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) super_.platform.client:client-feign:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=super_.platform.client -DartifactId=client-feign -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Path to dependency:
[ERROR]     1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]     2) super_.platform.client:client-feign:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR]   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

## Question

- Since the Git repo at Gitlab is private, I would imagine the Maven repository is also private. How to download that in Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Add the token information in the Maven repo passing the value through Environment Variable: `GITLAB_TOKEN`. You need to use the credentials section with an HTTP Header object.

```
    maven {
        url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22268428/packages/maven"
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            name "Private-Token"
            value System.env.GITLAB_TOKEN
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }
```

- After that, I was able to pull the library from the private Maven repository within the Gitlab repo.

```
GITLAB_TOKEN=1234556 gradle eclipse
```